# How can I batch reindex several elastic indexes?

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I have quite large numbers of indexes named like:

```
logstash-oidmsgcn_2016.12.01
logstash-oidmsgcn_2016.12.02
logstash-oidmsgcn_2016.12.03
...
logstash-oidmsgcn_2017.02.21
```

need to be indexed to names:

```
bk-logstash-oidmsgcn_2016.12.01
bk-logstash-oidmsgcn_2016.12.02
bk-logstash-oidmsgcn_2016.12.03
...
bk-logstash-oidmsgcn_2017.02.21
```

so, I only need to give their names a prefix in a batch way.
what can I do to get this job done?
I have referenced to [reindex api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html) and [bulk api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-bulk.html), but I still cannot get the hang of its way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do this be reindexing all your indices. If you are open to do this, you can do it with the [reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/docs-reindex.html) like this:

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "logstash-oidmsgcn_*"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "bk-logstash-oidmsgcn"
  },
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._index = 'bk-logstash-oidmsgcn_' + (ctx._index.substring('logstash-oidmsgcn_'.length(), ctx._index.length()))"
  }
}
```

Note that you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.

Comment: Thanks Val! But when I executed this command, an error occurred: "reason": "script_lang not supported [painless]". It may due to my elastic version 2.4. But After I remove the line "lang", Another error say: "reason": "scripts of type [inline], operation [update] and lang [groovy] are disabled"

Comment: Oh yes, you need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) as well of course

Comment: yes, this config works for me:  " script.engine.groovy.file.update: true" . Thank you again Val!